# Responsive Select Dropdwon option showing as black rectangular box in desktop Chrome browser mobile view

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image]

When I am testing my responsive HTML pages in cross browser compatibility, Am facing select drop down options problem in Chrome browser it's showing blank black rectangular as per the attachment.

> HTML

`<body>`
`<div class="container">`
`<div class="select-wrapper">`
`<select class="select" >`
`<option value="1" selected="selected">Option Number 1</option>`
`<option value="2">A Much Longer Option Than Option 1</option>`
`<option value="3">Option 3</option>`
`<option value="4">Option 4</option>`
`<option value="4">Option 4</option>`
`</select>`
    `<span class="select-icon entypo-arrow-combo"></span>`
  `</div>`
`</div>`
`</body>`

> CSS

`@import "compass/css3";`

`@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);`

`[class*="entypo-"]:before {`
  `font: 1.4em 'entypo', sans-serif;`
`}`

/*// Styles*/

`body {`
    `background: #fafafa;`
    `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`
    `color: #333;`
`}

`.container {`
    `margin: 5em auto 0;`
    `width: 25%;`
`}`

`.select-wrapper {`
    `background-color: #eee;`
    `border: 1px solid #aaa;`
    `color: #aaa;`
    `cursor: pointer;`
    `float: left;`
    `overflow: hidden;`
    `padding-right: 3em;`
    `position: relative;`
    `width: 100%;`
`}`

`.select {`
    `-webkit-appearance: none;`
    `background-color: #eee;`
    `border-width: 0;`
    `box-sizing: border-box;`
    `cursor: pointer;`
    `float: left;`
    `font-size: 1em;`
    `line-height: 1em;`
    `padding: 1em 1em;`
    `width: 100%;`
    `width: calc(100% + 2em);`
    `&:focus {`
        `outline: none;`
    `}`
`}`

`.select-icon {`
    `position: absolute;`
    `top: .8em;`
    `right: 1em;`
`}`

Comment: Can you please do us a favor and add your code? As I am having trouble using my telepathic power today!!

Comment: Hi Vinay thank you for your response I Know code is fully mesh please check any select box in chrome (Responsive select boxes only)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution : I'm using Google Chrome version 53.0.2785.143m after updating Chrome(Version 54.0.2840.59 m) It's working fine.